# Seems that quickCheck is telling me that False is not equal to False?

Tags: haskell

Been trying to write my own Prelude, and to write QuickCheck properties along with it. Writing Prelude is going well, but in doing the QuickCheck I have managed to get blocked early.  Here are snippets of the 2 files I have:

-- MyLude.hs

```
module MyLude where

import Prelude (Bool(..))

(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
(&&) True a = a
(&&) _ _ = False
```

-- MyLudeTest.hs

```
module MyLudeTest where

import qualified MyLude as P

prop_test_and a b = a && b == a P.&& b
```

Then in ghci I run:

```
:load MyLudeTest.hs
:m +Test.QuickCheck
quickCheck prop_test_and
```

and get the following error:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
False
False
```

What confuses me is that I have implemented (||) and implemented a quickcheck property for it that does pretty much the same thing the prop_test_and does, and that seems to have no problems. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just operator precedence at work. Your property is parsed as:

```
prop_test_and a b = a && (b == a) P.&& b
```

Comment: Oh boy, do I feel stupid. Yay for infix operator precedences! Any tips on how to recognize this type of error?

Comment: @Daniel: In many cases the program will fail to typecheck. However, that doesn't apply when all the sub-expressions are the same type as they are here.

Comment: You can see why the "or" worked properly: `a || (a == b) P.|| b` - since you probably wrote "or" correctly, it essentially simplifies to `a || b` which is always true, except when both `a` and `b` are `False`, in which case `a == b` is true!

Answer (score 5):

Precedence!

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> (False && False) == myand False False
True
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> False && False == myand False False
False
```

You're missing parens around your operators. Remember `(&&)` binds weaker (3) than `(==)` (4)